# Im using Heroku and its giving me an error when i start the bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im running into a problem where when i start the bot on heroku it gives me an error where it says it doesnt find the files that i have. This is the error im getting:

for better visual of error:
https://pastebin.com/EfTFd1Hi

```
 2022-05-05T19:14:57.183938+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
2022-05-05T19:14:57.183938+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-05-05T19:14:57.183939+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-05-05T19:14:57.183939+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
2022-05-05T19:14:57.183939+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2022-05-05T19:14:57.183940+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-05-05T19:14:57.183940+00:00 app[worker.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2022-05-05T19:14:57.183940+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
2022-05-05T19:14:57.436174+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-05T19:14:57.845666+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-05-05T19:17:42.947576+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-05-05T19:17:50.156798+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node /app/index.js`
2022-05-05T19:17:50.906062+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-05-05T19:17:52.639744+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-05-05T19:17:52.578290+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453128+00:00 app[worker.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453145+00:00 app[worker.1]:   throw err;
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453145+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ^
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453145+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453146+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../commands/moderation/manage.js'
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453146+00:00 app[worker.1]: Require stack:
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453146+00:00 app[worker.1]: - /app/index.js
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453146+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453147+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453147+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453147+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453147+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:20)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453148+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453148+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453148+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453148+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453148+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453148+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453149+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453149+00:00 app[worker.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2022-05-05T19:17:52.453149+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

Comment: It seems the path is not there. You can try to change path.

Comment: Your saying that the path is not correct since it saying `Cannot find module` try to change the path of your files.